# How to handle dependencies during construction time

Tags: java

I believe this is a classic and should have a design pattern, but besides dependency pattern and law of demeter, I can't really see the big picture:

To have a good testable and flexible application I want to:

1. Have a single entry into my application during construction time.
2. Have configuration loaded/parsed once and handed over to this entry point.
3. Let this entry point instantiate and configure all dependencies and then orchestrate it into an architecture.
4. And then let everything go over into runtime.

Constraint:

- A few Singleton as possible, best none.
- Only entry point knows about config, so it's easy to test dependencies
- Everything (all dependencies) should be easily testable.
- As few as possible exposed methods only for testing.

(Not working) Example:

```
// Main entrypoint
public App(Config config) {
    Dep1 dep1 = new Dep1(config.getDep1Conf());
    Dep2 dep2 = new Dep2(config.getDep2Conf());
    Dep3 dep3 = new Dep3(config.getDep3Conf());
    Dep4 dep4 = new Dep4(config.getDep4Conf());
    :

    this(dep1, dep2, dep3, dep4);
}

// Entry point for easy testing
public App(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2, Dep3 dep3, Dep4 dep4) {
    this.dep5 = Dep1.newInstance(Dep2);
    this.dep3 = dep3;
    this.dep4 = dep4;
    :
}
```

My question: **How would a template look like?**

Comment: Can you please define contruction time?

Comment: Construction time is the initial moment an application is started (e.g. from commandline) until all dependencies/instances are fully initialized and the system can operate/take requests/...

Comment: @fge Please provide a working example.